# Ошибка откладки MinGW на VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

Вот  ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот launch.json:

```
{
// Используйте IntelliSense, чтобы узнать о возможных атрибутах.
// Наведите указатель мыши, чтобы просмотреть описания существующих атрибутов.
// Для получения дополнительной информации посетите: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": []
}
```

Вот tasks.json:

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe сборка активного файла",
        "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Задача создана отладчиком."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Вот с_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++23",
        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

Comment: Может русские буквы в пути мешают? OneDrive наверное тоже не помогает.